# Custom GridView has wrong position Android

Tags: android, gridview

I created a custom GridView. It works but the `i` shows the wrong position in the log.

The log output is `0,1,2,0` I would expect `0,1,2,3,4,5` 
In my GridView all elements are there but the titles and images wrong after the 3rd element.

When I tap the elements I get the right index.

I'm new in Android. Is there a cache or do I have to clean the GridView? I found a lot of similar threads but no one could help. If you need more code please let me know.

```
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View gridViewAndroid;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    if (convertView == null) {

        gridViewAndroid = new View(mContext);
        gridViewAndroid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.course, null);

        TextView textViewAndroid = (TextView) gridViewAndroid.findViewById(R.id.android_gridview_text);
        ImageView imageViewAndroid = (ImageView) gridViewAndroid.findViewById(R.id.android_gridview_image);

        String url = "xxx/" + courses.get(i).getImageName();
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(url).into(imageViewAndroid);
        Log.d("IMAGE", "i" + i);
        textViewAndroid.setText(courses.get(i).getName());
    } else {
        gridViewAndroid = (View) convertView;
    }

    return gridViewAndroid;
}
```

Comment: convertView will be recycled to use. Move Log out of the if else statement and check the position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your views are recycled ,thats why this problem happening. try below code

Add a view holder inside your adapter

```
static class ViewHolder {
     TextView textViewAndroid;
     ImageView imageViewAndroid;
}
```

Change your `getView()` to below code

```
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {   
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

         convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.course, null);
         holder = new ViewHolder();
         holder.textViewAndroid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.android_gridview_text);

         holder.imageViewAndroid = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.android_gridview_image);
         convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
         holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

   String url = "xxx/" + courses.get(i).getImageName();
   Picasso.with(mContext).load(url).into(holder.imageViewAndroid);
   Log.d("IMAGE", "i" + i);
   holder.textViewAndroid.setText(courses.get(i).getName());
   return convertView;
}
```

Put the static class inside your `public class X extends BaseAdapter`